# How to gets text array data from postgres to c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

I have called function from postgres & output is like

[image]

I am using windows form to display data, i have used npgsql for connecting c# and postgres d.b.
my BL class function is given below

```
    public List<User> view_data()
    {

        NpgsqlDataReader rdr;
        List<User> lstUser = new List<User>();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from public.get_user_details", con);

        rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
           
            lstUser.Add(new User()
            {
                id = rdr.GetInt16(Convert.ToString(rdr["id"])),
                roleName = rdr.GetString(Convert.ToString(rdr["rolename"])),
                firstName = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("firstname")),
                lastName = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("lastname"))
       
        });

        }
        rdr.Close();

        return lstUser;

    }
```

Getting error on rolename. error is cannot convert string to string[]

my User class is given below

```
public class User
{
    public int id
    { get; set; }
    public string firstName
    { get; set; }
    public string lastName
    { get; set; }
    public string email
    { get; set; }
    public string userName
    { get; set; }
    public string[] roleName
    { get; set; }

}
```

My question is how to assign text array data in c# using npqsql data reader?

Getting error on this area => roleName = rdr.GetString(Convert.ToString(rdr["rolename"]))

postgres gives role name output is text array. ie; in one column contains multiple values. ie; {admin,user}. So need to set postgres text array into c# format using data reader.

Comment: You need to change `public string[] roleName { get; set; }` to `public string roleName { get; set; }`

Comment: I have changed roleName[] to roleName as you said, but getting error => IndexOutOfRangeException: Field not found in row: System.String[]

Comment: postgres gives role name output is text array. ie; in one column contains multiple values. ie; {admin,user}. So need to set text array into c# format using data reader. Can you help me for this.

Comment: I'm note well versed with 1. Direct SQL access in C# (I suggest to use an ORM like Entity Framework) and 2. Postgres. But in my SQL experience, multiple values inside one cell breaks the first normal form and instead you should replace it with a relation to a "roles" table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your code as it is but replace the SQL query with this one below. It joins (aggregates) the contents of the `roleName` array into a single comma-separated list string. So instead of

```sql
select * from public.get_user_details
```

use this one:

```sql
select 
  id,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  array_to_string(rolename, ',') as rolename
from public.get_user_details
```

I have added new lines for readability, you can remove them. And btw `select *` in production code is more often than not a recipe for trouble.